# disappearing mouse pointer with fractional scaling, multi-monitor setup (vertical), Intel Driver

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, mouse-pointer

Running Ubuntu 20.10 GNOME (no special extensions), Intel driver and "TearFree" option set on two monitors with one being "Portrait Right" and fractional scaling on at 125%.

Mouse pointer completely disappears (smoothly, no flickering etc) at the edge of the vertical screen, this ONLY HAPPENS:

- when using Intel driver
- with fractional scaling on
- Portrait Right (but not Left) setup of the monitor

Any ideas what could be causing this and possible fixes? Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Additionnally I use a tweaked version of Ubuntu using X11 instead of Wayland.
I found some instruction that helped me solve the problem.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358992/cursor-flickers-with-xrandr-scaling

The trick I used is the additional xorg conf file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

This is what I applied. But in the link some people explain that the file should be /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf.

Use at your own risk (and don't do like me and use some code you don't really understand).